# Prove: $\exists (a,b)\in A | \forall (x,y)\in A : \cos (x)+\cos (xy)\leq\cos(a)+\cos(ab)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
A=\left\{(x,y) | -1\leq x\leq 1, |x|\leq y, x^2-2x+y^2\leq0 \right\}
$$

Prove: $\exists (a,b)\in A | \forall (x,y)\in A :$
$$
\cos (x)+\cos (xy)\leq\cos(a)+\cos(ab)
$$

I don't have any lead so a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the last polynomial in the definition of $A$ mean? Is it perchance supposed to be equal to zero or some such?

Comment: Sorry. It's now fixed.

Comment: $(0,0)$ seems to be a solution. Such an easy answer makes the problem statement validity a little dubious.

Comment: @Yves Daoust 
It's supposed to be a basic question I think

Comment: @YvesDaoust You also have to do some arguing that it actually is a solution, though admittedly it's pretty much high school level math.

Comment: We barely scratched the surface of multi-variable functions in this course.

Comment: @drf: why should I, this is a comment ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh you misunderstand. I suppose I should have said "One also has to do ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider what happens if $x=0$ and what you know about the cosine function.